# React native webview bridge

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi guys I have made a webview app that opens a specific webpage and i just need to add a button which will have options to add a photo from gallery or camera? what resources/concepts should i read and understand before I attempt this problem ...

Comment: Do you need to add a button from webview or what?

Comment: Need to have a button somewhere on the web view  app/website to open upload picture options

Comment: Just add `<input type="file" accept="image/*">` to your site, what exactly you don't understand in current problem?

Comment: Thanks but I need to use web view component with a react native button component to get access to two options upload image via gallery or camera

Comment: You can't access react native (or to be specific native) components from your webview. You either put  `input type=file` into website, Neither You put reactnative button, but in this situation I don't see why you put webview in the scope of the "problem"

Comment: The problem is a bit weird and so assuming we don’t have access to the website code , we just have to have a button somewhere on the display where web view is also a part

Comment: Webview bridge is it a good place to start

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161408/discussion-between-naveen-dinushka-and-deathangel908).